# How to center the text of navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, center

I am not very comfortable with CSS. According, to this code. How can I center the `My Website` text in my navbar ?

Here is a JS fiddle working example : https://jsfiddle.net/cvp8w2tf/2/
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 has a bunch of utility classes you can use, you shouldn't have to write any custom CSS to accomplish what you want.

Inspecting the navbar, I see that it doesn't stretch the full width of the page, so you'll want to [use the `w-100` utility class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/sizing/) (it sets the width of the element to 100%).

This will keep the nav item left-aligned still. Since `.navbar` is a flex container, all you have to do is [add the `justify-content-center` utility class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content) that will center all the content within the navbar.

So the following `<nav>` element:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light text-primary navbar-personalized">
```

Should become:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light text-primary navbar-personalized w-100 justify-content-center">
```

That should give you what you want.